# undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast' using libc++ on ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, linker, clang, libc++

I'm trying to compile a test case that employs `dynamic_cast` using libc++, which was compiled according to ["Build on Linux using CMake and libsupc++"](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual void f(){ std::cout << "Virtual A" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~A(){}
};

struct B : public A
{
    void f() { std::cout << "Virtual B" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~B(){}
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new B;
    B *b = dynamic_cast<B *>(a);
    delete a;
}
```

I'm on ubuntu 13.04 and compiling with `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`.

Why I'm getting `undefined reference to '__dynamic_cast'`? How to solve it?

#### EDIT

Looks like it has something to do with libc++abi [since I'm seeing `__dynamic_cast` prototype in the spec](http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/spec.html). I expected the `libsupc++` first build option to work without such issues... and trying to compile libc++abi on linux [is another issue itself](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-February/019907.html).

This seems related to [Compiling with Clang using Libc++ undefined references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7016730).

If this is indeed the problem, is there a straightforward process to use libc++ on linux that can compile that short snippet, or is it just not yet supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [`libcxxrt`](https://github.com/pathscale/libcxxrt/) to replace the pretty Mac specific [`libc++abi`](http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/) (the website says only Darwin is supported). It provides a working implementation for BSD's Clang+libc++ setup, I believe it has been used with success on Linux as well.