# std::cerr on linux with clang++ and libc++ causes SIGABRT

Tags: linux, clang++, libc++

I'm trying to get  a simple program running on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 compiled with clang++ 3.3 libc++ libc++abi .

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  try {
    std::cerr << "Test cerr \n";
  } catch (...) {
    std::cout << "catch exception";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Writing to std::cerr prints the message, but results in SIGABRT.

However, writing to std::cout works fine.

Here the ldd output of the executable:

```
$ldd cerr_test
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffce5ff000)
libc++abi.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libc++abi.so.1 (0x00007fa4079fd000)
libc++.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libc++.so.1 (0x00007fa407759000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa40745c000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa407246000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa406e87000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa406c69000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa406a61000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa407c55000)
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to fix this?

Here is the backtrace:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Test cerr

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff704e425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff704e425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7051b8b in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff792a437 in std::uncaught_exception() () from /usr/local/lib/libc++.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff79324e2 in std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry() ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libc++.so.1
#4  0x000000000040118e in std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> > (__os=..., __str=0x401784 "Test cerr \n")
    at /usr/local/include/c++/v1/ostream:990
#5  0x0000000000400d41 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe728) at cerr_test.cpp:5
(gdb)
```

Comment: can you compile with debug and post crash stacktrace?

Comment: sure. just added the backtrace to the post

Comment: On my Linux system (32-bit gcc 4.7 and clang 3.2) it works fine.
Which compiling options are you using ?

Comment: also to not. enclosing the std::cerr call with a try catch block results in the same backtrace... it still says std:: uncaught_exception..

Comment: I am compiling it with "clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o cerr_test cerr_test.cpp -L /usr/local/lib/ -lc++abi -I /usr/local/include/c++/v1/ -nostdinc++" . I compiled clang and libc++ according to this post https://plus.google.com/u/0/+DeWittClinton/posts/Vr7y8TPsKgR

Comment: can you update your code with try/catch exactly the way you are doing it?

Comment: yes, just updated the code.

Comment: as suggested here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16274107) I recommend libcxxrt on linux.

Comment: When you built libc++, did it give this warning: `#warning uncaught_exception not yet implemented`?

Comment: just started the build again and yes there is a warning.. Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: Yes.  Implement it. ;-)  Easier said than done. :-(  There is a suggestion to use libcxxrt on linux.  I'm guessing that libcxxrt implements uncaught_exception on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works finally by using libcxxrt instead libc++abi as suggested by @chico