# Install libc++ on ubuntu

Tags: clang, libc++

I am wondering what is the right/easy way to install a binary libc++ on Ubuntu, in my case Trusty aka 14.04?

On the LLVM web site there are apt packages http://apt.llvm.org/ and I have used these to install 3.9. However these packages don't seem to include libc++. I install the libc++-dev package but that seems to be a really old version. There are also binaries that can be downloaded http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.9.0. These do seem to contain libc++ but I'm not sure if I can just copy bits of this into places like /usr/include/c++/v1, in fact I'm not really sure what bits I would need to copy. I am aware I can use libc++ from an alternate location as documented here http://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html which I have tried. However I can't modify the build system of the large code base I work on to do this.

So is three any reason the apt packages don't include libc++ and any pointers to installing a binary would be gratefully recieved.

Answer (score 38):

### How to build libc++ on Ubuntu 16.04

I had a similar issue as you do. While testing clang with libstdc++ worked fine with C++11 and C++14 there still might be licensing issues with libstdc++. So I ended up installing Clang toolchain from their repos and compiling libc++ on Ubuntu 16.04.

**Disclaimer:** This post is summary of long search on how to build the `libc++` on Ubuntu Linux. Many of the posts I found in 2017 were either outdated or described a partial solution on other systems e.g. CentOS. Links to these posts are:

- [Hacking with Clang llvm abi and llvm libc](https://github.com/maidsafe-archive/MaidSafe/wiki/Hacking-with-Clang-llvm-abi-and-llvm-libc)
- [Building Clang and libc++ on Ubuntu Linux](http://Building%20Clang%20and%20libc++%20on%20Ubuntu%20Linux)
- [How to Build libcxx and libcxxabi by clang on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840088/how-to-build-libcxx-and-libcxxabi-by-clang-on-centos-7)

Here are the steps to build LLVM + Clang + libc++ from the 4.0 release branch:

1. Install the key of LLVM Repositories

   ```
   # apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get install -y vim curl && \
        curl -q https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key |apt-key add -
   ```
2. Create a new new APT Repository File (you can also exclude 2 lines referring to v3.9 repos)

   ```bash
   # cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/llvm-repos.list << EOF
        deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial main
        deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial main
        deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.9 main
        deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.9 main
        deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-4.0 main
        deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-4.0 main
        EOF
   ```
3. Install Clang and all Packages needed to build libc++ from LLVM repos

   ```
       # apt-get update && apt-get install -y clang-4.0 clang-4.0-doc \
      libclang-common-4.0-dev libclang-4.0-dev libclang1-4.0 libclang1-4.0-dbg \
      libllvm4.0 libllvm4.0-dbg lldb-4.0 llvm-4.0 llvm-4.0-dev llvm-4.0-runtime \
      clang-format-4.0 python-clang-4.0 liblldb-4.0-dev lld-4.0 libfuzzer-4.0-dev \
      subversion cmake
   ```
4. Create an alternative for C++ compiler and linker. This is not a must, but lets you switch compilers or linkers if needed. Also some build files needed `cc` or `c++` or `clang++` as far as I remember. Keep in mind, that we switch to LLD linker as default:

   ```
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/clang-4.0 100 \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/clang++-4.0 100 \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-4.0 100 \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-4.0 100 \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ld ld /usr/bin/ld.lld-4.0 10 \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ld ld /usr/bin/ld.gold 20 \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ld ld /usr/bin/ld.bfd 30 \
    && ld --version && echo 3 | update-alternatives --config ld && ld --version
   ```
5. Checkout sources of `libc++` and `libc++abi`:

   ```
   $ cd /tmp
   $ svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/branches/release_40/ libcxx
   $ svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxxabi/branches/release_40/ libcxxabi
   $ mkdir -p libcxx/build libcxxabi/build
   ```
6. To run `libc++` on Linux one needs ABI compatibility to the standard library, e.g. libstdc++. This is where `libc++abi` comes into game. The only problem is that it needs `libc++` to be on the system for which it is build. Thus `libc++` is built in 2 steps. First: without any ABI compatibility. But it will be used for bootstrapping of ABI lib and than the second step is to recompile `libc++` with the proper ABI present on system:

   Bootstrapping => build `libc++` without proper ABI:

   ```
   cd /tmp/libcxx/build
   cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-config-4.0\
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr .. \
   && make install
   ```

   Building `libc++abi` with `libstdc++` compatible ABI:

   ```
   cd /tmp/libcxxabi/build
   CPP_INCLUDE_PATHS=`echo | c++ -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only 2>&1 \
     |grep ' /usr'|tr '\n' ' '|tr -s ' ' |tr ' ' ';'`
   CPP_INCLUDE_PATHS="/usr/include/c++/v1/;$CPP_INCLUDE_PATHS"
   cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI=libstdc++ \
         -DLIBCXX_LIBSUPCXX_INCLUDE_PATHS="$CPP_INCLUDE_PATHS" \
         -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
         -DLLVM_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-config-4.0 \
         -DLIBCXXABI_LIBCXX_INCLUDES=../../libcxx/include  ..
   make install
   ```

   Rebuild `libc++` with proper ABI lib deployed on system:

   ```
   cd /tmp/libcxx/build
   cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
         -DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI=libcxxabi -DLLVM_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-config-4.0\
         -DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI_INCLUDE_PATHS=../../libcxxabi/include .. \
   && make install
   ```
7. Create a test file to check whether everything works fine. IMO you should also test `cerr` stream, as previously it was not supported with the `libc++abi` and there were some segfaults. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590583/stdcerr-on-linux-with-clang-and-libc-causes-sigabrt).

   Create a test.cpp file:

   ```cpp
   #include <iostream>
   int main()
   {
     using namespace std;
     cout << "[OK] Hello world to cout!" << endl;
     cerr << "[OK] Hello world to cerr!" << endl;
     clog << "[OK] Hello world to clog!" << endl;
     return 0;
   }
   ```

   And compile it and run it using this command line:

   `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi test.cpp && ./a.out`

### Reason there is no package

I found libc++ packages for Ubuntu but they are a bit behind recent version: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libc++-dev

Why they are not current, I can't answer, but my guess is that LLVM+Clang can work with mostly any Standard Library, whereas libc++ as you see must be linked to particular runtime ABI and might heavily depend on available C runtime library. I agree there should be a package which covers 90% of the cases. May be this is just the lack of resources. [Searching the mailing archive](https://www.google.de/search?q=libc%2B%2B%20site%3Alists.alioth.debian.org%2Fpipermail%2Fpkg-llvm-team%2F&oq=libc%2B%2B%20site%3Alists.alioth.debian.org%2Fpipermail%2Fpkg-llvm-team%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57.26494j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) did not bring up anything special.

Comment: Great details. The fact that you had to go through all this is odd to me. There is already a great apt-get package for everything else, why not have libc++ in it. I can't believe the libc++ developers don't want their stuff used but that is the effect. I know of a number of companies that use clang on Linux but none use libc++ because it's not in the package. Sure you can call them lazy but I can understand why they just default to using libstdc++. Actually a couple of them didn't even realize they weren't using libc++ as they just assumed it would be there.

Comment: @goneskiing Feel free to accept the answer, if it answers your question :)

Comment: Note for clang-6.0:
* Replace "4.0" and "release_40" with "6.0" and "release_50" will do.
* `-DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI` and `-DLIBCXX_LIBSUPCXX_INCLUDE_PATHS` are not required

Answer (score 30):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc++-dev
```

Comment: This gives a 3.7 version. As the poster said, rather old.

Comment: `sudo apt install libc++-dev libc++abi-dev` worked for me (needed ABI package also to compile using clang).

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer gave me some errors (it is Nov 2021 currently). Also, `sudo apt install libc++-dev libc++abi-dev` did not provide the latest libc++. Here is an alternate solution.

Use the [LLVM apt package maintainer](https://apt.llvm.org/)'s script:

`sudo bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"`

This automatically sets up the apt repositories and gives you the latest LLVM toolchain.

`clang-13 --version`

Since you now have the latest LLVM packages available from http://apt.llvm.org you can install the latest libc++. First determine the latest version:

`apt search libc++ | grep libc++`

Then:

`sudo apt install libc++-13-dev libc++abi-13-dev`

Optionally, you can use `update-alternatives` to make your system use `clang-13` instead of the default. There is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/junkdog) for that:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/junkdog/70231d6953592cd6f27def59fe19e50d/raw/update-alternatives-clang.sh
chmod +x update-alternatives-clang.sh
sudo ./update-alternatives-clang.sh 13 1000
```

Now:

```
clang --version
Debian clang version 13.0.1-++20211110062941+9dc7d6d5e326-1~exp1~20211110183517.26
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Comment: before running `update-alternatives-clang.sh` I also installed `clang-tools-13`, `clang-format-13`, and `clang-tidy-13`

Comment: Many thanks!! You saved my evening! I just installed LLVM-13 on my Debian 10 machine and could not for my life understand why #include <iostream> did not work! Still, I have a faint memory this is the second time I assumed a full LLVM install would come with all you need to clang++ build with the llvm tool chain. That the libc++ has to be added separately makes sense o n l y once you read up on the incitements for being gnu compatible. Being a developer and having to tinker with the system is like being an architect having to solve what batteries works with what power tools ;)

Comment: Yep, similar thing happened to me. It’s quite mystifying at first.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get a working libc++ is to install the entire 3.9.0 toolchain under `/usr/local`. This will allow /usr/local/bin/clang++ to find the headers correctly and also allow the linker to find /usr/local/lib/libc++.so.

Answer (score 0):

check my shell-script automation version:

https://github.com/sailfish009/llvm_all

```
$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libedit-dev swig git

$ git clone https://github.com/sailfish009/llvm_all

$ git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project

$ cd llvm_all

$ cp *.sh ../llvm-project/

$ cd ../llvm-project/

$ ./set.sh

$ ./install.sh

$ clang++ --version
clang version 11.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project 032251e34d17c1cbf21e7571514bb775ed5cdf30)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Answer (score -1):

Just build it yourself, as explained [here](https://libcxx.llvm.org/BuildingLibcxx.html#the-default-build). I added `-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang` to use clang as the compiler:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
$ cd llvm-project
$ mkdir build
$ cmake -G Ninja -S runtimes -B build -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang # Configure for clang++
$ ninja -C build cxx cxxabi unwind # Build
$ ninja -C build check-cxx check-cxxabi check-unwind # Test
$ ninja -C build install-cxx install-cxxabi install-unwind # Install
```