# Running the coroutines example under Ubuntu 16.04 gives "'experimental/coroutine' file not found"

Tags: c++, clang++, coroutine

Looking at clang-5.0 [release notes](http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html) it says that "[C++ coroutines TS](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4680.pdf) has landed", and suggests to check out [this example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dth1IO5q8Oe31ew2) to get started. I obviously can run the example online, so I decided to try on my Ubuntu Server 16.04 Xenial machine.

From a clean installation, I just tried

```
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-5.0 main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y clang-5.0 libc++-dev
```

And went straight for

```
clang++-5.0 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++2a "-fcoroutines-ts" "-stdlib=libc++" -o test.out test.cpp
```

(`test.cpp` being a copy-and-paste of [the aforementioned example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dth1IO5q8Oe31ew2))

However, I just get

```
coroutines.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'experimental/coroutine' file not found
#include <experimental/coroutine>
```

So I can imagine I am missing something, either to install or in the compilation flags. I tried to look online but I couldn't find anything useful.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the repository you linked provides only the toolchain, but not the headers.

Installing **libc++-dev** you installed the package from the Ubuntu repositories, which do not include the header files in the experimental directory.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332406/install-libc-on-ubuntu) question to build libc++ by yourself and set up the toolchain appropriately.

Comment: Thank you! I had actually seen that question, but it seems to refer to version 4 of `libc++`. I tried to replace all `4.0` with `5.0` but it produced a lot of errors..

Comment: Yes, the linked answer requires a bit of thinkering... have you tried to install the **libstdc++-5-dev** package with apt-get install libstdc++-5-dev ?

Comment: I haven't! Are `libstdc++` and `libc++` the same thing? I am sorry, I tend to get confused about these issues.

Comment: No they aren't the same. libstdc++ is the package providing the **GNU Standard C++ library** while libc++ is the **LLVM** one. I suggested to install the libstdc++-5-dev to fix the errors you received trying to compile clang manually.

Comment: Apparently, `libstdc++-5-dev` was already installed in my system. I even tried changing `-stdlib=libc++` to `-stdlib=stdlibc++` but no dice, I get the same error message. I tried to `find` any file called `coroutine` in the system and there is none.

Comment: You can't mix the GNU standard library with LLVM compiler. There's no file named coroutine because the libc++ package you have doesn't provide it. I'm afraid, the only viable solution is to recompile libc++ by yourself.