# Ubuntu 18.04 error: libc++_shared.so is missing

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, minecraft, libc++

I want to run the minecraft bedrock edition(mcpe) on Ubuntu 18.04. Here is the tutorial that I used **https://markperez.dev/blog/install-minecraft-bedrock-linux-any-distro/**.
And I see this error **after installing this program and running minecraft .apk file:**

```
14:26:48 Info  [Launcher] CPU: GenuineIntel Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz
14:26:48 Info  [Launcher] CPU supports SSSE3: YES
14:26:48 Trace [Launcher] Loading hybris libraries
14:26:48 Trace [HybrisUtils] Loaded OS library /usr/share//mcpelauncher/libs/native/libfmod.so.9.16
14:26:48 Trace [HybrisUtils] Loaded OS library libm.so.6
14:26:48 Trace [HybrisUtils] Loaded OS library libz.so.1
14:26:48 Trace [Launcher] Loading Minecraft library
linkerterminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Failed to load Minecraft: Cannot load library: link_image[1965]:     0 could not load needed library 'libc++_shared.so' for 'libminecraftpe.so' (load_library[1115]: Library 'libc++_shared.so' not found)
Signal 6 received
Backtrace elements: 13
#0 /usr/bin/mcpelauncher-client(_ZN12CrashHandler12handleSignalEiPv+0xc5) [0x567cc729]
#1 linux-gate.so.1(__kernel_sigreturn+0) [0xf7fd0b70]
#2 linux-gate.so.1(__kernel_vsyscall+0x9) [0xf7fd0b59]
#3 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc2) [0xf78a2882]
#4 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x121) [0xf78a3d11]
#5 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x6e97d) [0xf7c0097d]
#6 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x76174) [0xf7c08174]
#7 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x761dd) [0xf7c081dd]
#8 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x764dc) [0xf7c084dc]
#9 /usr/bin/mcpelauncher-client(_ZN14MinecraftUtils16loadMinecraftLibERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x183) [0x567cdc03]
#10 /usr/bin/mcpelauncher-client(main+0xff8) [0x567686d4]
#11 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1) [0xf788de91]
#12 /usr/bin/mcpelauncher-client(+0x1dc0f1) [0x567670f1]
Dumping stack...
Process exited with unexpected exit code: 6
```

But this is not main issue. ***The main issue is there are missing *libc++.so* library.*** I tried to install libc++1 library, but that not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc++-dev
```

[Have a look at other posts also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332406/install-libc-on-ubuntu)

Comment: [Have a look at here also](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libc++1_6.0-2_amd64.deb.html)