# android 7.1 cannot compiled with kati

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-source, clang++

When i try to build android 7.1 from source code i get folloging error:

```
build/kati/flags.h:18:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
```

Detailed Log:

```
prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -fPIC -no-canonical-prefixes -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   --gcc-toolchain=prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8 -fstack-protector-strong    --gcc-toolchain=prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8 --sysroot prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/sysroot -Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/x86_64-linux/bin -target x86_64-linux-gnu   -Wsign-promo -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override   --gcc-toolchain=prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8 --sysroot prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/sysroot -isystem prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/x86_64-linux/include/c++/4.8 -isystem prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/x86_64-linux/include/c++/4.8/x86_64-linux -isystem prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/x86_64-linux/include/c++/4.8/backward -target x86_64-linux-gnu -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/affinity.o build/kati/affinity.cc
In file included from build/kati/affinity.cc:17:
build/kati/flags.h:18:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [build/kati/Makefile.ckati:89: out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/affinity.o] Error 1
```

I installed all required libraries, and clang++ can build test project without any errors.

Comment: Are you sure you have libc++ dev ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704680/9458132

Comment: i already installed this library, but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because of incompatible `clang++` version with `gcc-toolchain`. I fixed it with including correct version of `prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/`