# Is it valid to cast from A* to B* via dynamic_cast when A and B haven't a common ancestor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, casting, dynamic-cast

Both *clang 3.5.0* and *g++ 4.9.0* [compile the following code fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e039d1b802c2a8e) (with `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`) and the program outputs `true`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

struct B
{
    virtual ~B() = default;
};

struct C : A, B
{
    virtual ~C() = default;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    A* ap = &c;
    B* bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(ap);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (bp != nullptr) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you suspect the behaviour you see may be wrong? (It's a valid question either way, but it would make a difference in what a good answer should focus on.)

Comment: @hvd I was almost sure that it was not possible. I don't know why. :)

Comment: @hvd I mean I assumed that the output of the program should be `false`, not that use of `dynamic_cast` may be invalid in some cases,  of course.

Comment: Note that this won't link with [`libc++`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dcadb2d30be777b).

Comment: Just to add some information regarding this scenario. In case "ap" was a pointer to some class not related to the hierarchy of B, this dynamic_cast would return null and you must check if "bp" is NULL before dereferencing it. Another way to do this is by using a reference with dynamic_cast: `B* bp = nullptr;
    try{
        bp = &(dynamic_cast<B&>(*ap));
    } catch (...) {
    std::cout << "exception" << std::endl;
    }`

Comment: @0x499602D2 There's some kind of ABI issue with clang on Coliru, it often [needs -lsupc++ for runtime support](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/248d924cf162ba86).

Comment: @fhsilva Yes, I know it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as per §5.2.7 [expr.dynamic.cast], for `dynamic_cast<T>(v)` (emphasis mine):

> If C is the class type to which T points or refers, the run-time check logically executes as follows:
>
> — If, in the most derived object pointed (referred) to by v, v points (refers) to a public base class
>   subobject of a C object, and if only one object of type C is derived from the subobject pointed (referred) to by v the result points (refers) to that C object.
>
> — **Otherwise, if v points (refers) to a public base class subobject of the most derived object, and the
>   type of the most derived object has a base class, of type C, that is unambiguous and public, the result points (refers) to the C subobject of the most derived object.**
>
> — Otherwise, the run-time check fails.

In your case, `v` refers to a most derived object that is an instance of your `C`, but the static type of `v` is a pointer to the public base class `A`. The `C` base class mentioned in the quotation is your `B`.

Comment: Also relevant to someone who might just be wondering it: 11.2.2 - `In the absence of an access-specifier for a base class, public is assumed when the derived class is defined with the class-key struct and private is assumed when the class is defined with the class-key class.`

Comment: @MarcoA., I guess that would be good to note, yes. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcoA. How does your quote relate to the question or answer?

Comment: @Constructor Just noting that if you used `class` instead of `struct` the above won't work

Comment: Note that this won't link with [`libc++`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dcadb2d30be777b).

Comment: @MarcoA. Ah, sorry. I usually use `struct`s in my questions and answers thanks to this wonderful simplification.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It is interesting. Why?

Comment: @Constructor Seems to be a problem with the libc++ abi. [Here's a related post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271976/undefined-reference-to-dynamic-cast-using-libc-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. That's sometimes known as *cross-casting*, and will succeed if they are both base sub-objects of the same derived object, as they are here.

`dynamic_cast` is necessary, since the conversion needs the run-time information that both are part of a `C` object. To statically cast, you'd have to explicitly convert to `C*` first.

Comment: Thank you. *Cross-casting* is a new term for me.