# Does clang++ 12 support C++20 std::construct_at?

Tags: c++, clang++, c++20

I'm playing with recently approved C++20 standard features `std::construct_at()` and trying to get more familiar with them...

I've built an example based on the [example from CppReference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at):

```
#include <memory>

struct S {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main() {
    std::allocator<S> alloc;
    S * s = alloc.allocate(1);
    std::construct_at(s, 42, 43); // GCC 10.2 OK Clang 12 NOT
    std::destroy_at(s);
    alloc.deallocate(s, 1);
    s = nullptr;
}
```

The code above builds fine with the latest stable GCC:
`gcc-10.2 test.cpp -std=c++2a -lstdc++`

But I can't get it to compile with Clang 12 (trunk) or 10 (stable).
`clang-12 test.cpp -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++`
with error:

```
test.cpp:11:5: error: no matching function for call to 'construct_at'
    std::construct_at(s, 42, 43); // GCC 10.2 OK Clang 12 NOT
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/clang/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:903:16: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Tp = S, _Args = <int, int>]: no matching constructor for initialization of 'S'
constexpr _Tp* construct_at(_Tp* __location, _Args&& ...__args) {
               ^
1 error generated.
```

Am I using the parameter pack incorrectly?
Clang C++20 [feature list](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) doesn't seem to indicate it is supported yet?
I've tried with the GCC toolchain in Clang and same results: `--gcc-toolchain=/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0`

I obtain similar falures with online compiler explorers.

If I explicitly construct an S by initializer-list (which may very well defeat the purpose of the in-place construct) `std::construct_at(s, S{42, 43});` then the program compiles but fails at linking.

Is this approach constructing a temporary defeating the construct_at purpose?
What if I tack on a std::move? `std::construct_at(s, std::move(S{42, 43}));` Online compiler explorers seem to indicate more assembly required with the move, perhaps there's an elision without it (and I created a pessimism by adding the move)?

The linking error is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/test-b07239.o: in function `std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt3__120__throw_length_errorEPKc[_ZNSt3__120__throw_length_errorEPKc]+0x12): undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt3__120__throw_length_errorEPKc[_ZNSt3__120__throw_length_errorEPKc]+0x30): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::length_error'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt3__120__throw_length_errorEPKc[_ZNSt3__120__throw_length_errorEPKc]+0x3a): undefined reference to `std::length_error::~length_error()'
```

Apparently `-stdlib=libc++` [should be used linked with an ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016730/compiling-with-clang-using-libc-undefined-references): `-lstdc++` solve the linking error while `-lc++abi` still misses:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/test-bb0950.o: in function `std::length_error::length_error(char const*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt12length_errorC2EPKc[_ZNSt12length_errorC2EPKc]+0x23): undefined reference to `std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)'
```

Could it be I am missing yet another library for the logic_error?

Back to the key questions at hand:

- Does Clang supports `std::construct_at(s, 42, 43);` ?
- Is there a performance hit to use the initializer-list construction? With/o move?

Comment: Very few have access to `clang++`12 (I'm at 9 myself) Stuff _will_ change if you try _HEAD_ features in the language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `construct_at`. `S` is an aggregate; outside of its default and copy/move constructors, it has no constructors to be called. So `S` can only be constructed with values through aggregate initialization.

This normally requires a braced-init-list (eg: `S{3, 5}`). But C++20 includes a feature that allows aggregate initialization to work through constructor syntax (eg: `S(3, 5)`) so long as the parameters wouldn't call a default or copy/move constructor (in which case, it'll call one of them).

But Clang [doesn't implement that feature as of yet](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20). So `construct_at` fails to construct the aggregate.

Comment: I like how people just now these things! "_`std::construct_at(s, 42, 43); // GCC 10.2 OK Clang 12 NOT`_" +1

Comment: Relevant reference may be: [P0960R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html)

Comment: From being at the forefront of modern C++ innovation Clang/libc++ development seems to have staggered recently. It is still lacking full C+17 support and even is far behind in C++20. There are C++20 PRs from an year ago that nobody seems to be looking at yet. I wonder if proper concepts support will finally make such issues more readable to the less knowledgable.